# Dictionary value access using ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible, ansible-facts

I have a situation where we have 2 dictionary defined in ansible role default and the selection of dictionary is based of an input variable. I want to set the fact with one of the dict's specific key value.

Below is the example code:

**test.yml** paybook content:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role1
  tags: ['role1']
```

roles/role1/tasks/main.yml content:

```
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    node_vip: "{% if node_vip_run == 'no' %}node_vip_no{% elif node_vip_run == 'yes' %}node_vip_yes{% endif %}"

- debug:
    var: node_vip
    verbosity: 1

- debug:
    var: "{{ node_vip }}.ece_endpoint"
    verbosity: 1

- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    ece_endpoint_fact: "{{ node_vip[ece_endpoint] }}"

- debug:
    var: ece_endpoint
    verbosity: 1
```

roles/role1/defaults/main.yml content:

```
node_vip_yes:
  ece_endpoint: "https://1.1.1.1:8080"
  cac_endpoint: "https:2.2.2.2:8080"
node_vip_no:
  ece_endpoint: "http://3.3.3.3:8080"
  cac_endpoint: "http:4.4.4.4:8080"
```

Run playbook:

```
ansible-playbook test.yaml --extra-vars 'node_vip_run=no' -v
```

The set fact of variable "ece_endpoint_fact" should have value "https://1.1.1.1:8080 OR [http://3.3.3.3:8080"](http://3.3.3.3:8080%22) depending on the parameter input in ansible command. But I keep on getting below error:

```
TASK [role1 : set fact] *******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute u'http://3.3.3.3:8080'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/roles/role1/tasks/main.yml': line 46, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: set fact\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Please suggest what needs to be done to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you set `node_vip` to either the literal string `"node_vip_no"` or `"node_vip_yes"`. But if you change it to do `{{ node_vip_no }}` / `{{ node_vip_yes }}`, then `node_vip` will have the value of the **variable** `node_vip_no` / `node_vip_yes` instead of being a literal string.

```yaml
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    node_vip: "{% if node_vip_run == 'no' %}{{ node_vip_no }}{% elif node_vip_run == 'yes' %}{{ node_vip_yes }}{% endif %}"
```

This will have `node_vip`'s value be something like:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "node_vip": {
        "cac_endpoint": "https:2.2.2.2:8080",
        "ece_endpoint": "https://1.1.1.1:8080"
    }
}
```

Then in your other `set_fact`, it should work if you put quotes around the property name:

```yaml
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    ece_endpoint_fact: "{{ node_vip['ece_endpoint'] }}"
#                     Added quotes  ^            ^
```